# How to use Relative URL for HTML links in Site Template for a Hero WebPart

Tags: sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online

I'm using Office365 for my company's Intanet Portal.

We have customized a SP Site and added a Hero WebPart on Modern Home Page, Edited the Links in that Webpart which points to some List and Lib URL in the same site.

List and Lib URL Links:

/sites/test/DocLib1

/sites/test/DocLib2

Then we saved the Site as a template and created new Project Sites based on the template.

Everything works fine, but the Links in Hero web-part is pointing to the Site Template Libraries URL and not the newly created Site Library URL.

I need to make this work, I can apply custom code also using JS or any other way.

Please help

We are using Modern Site Pages.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use properties from SharePoint JavaScript object _spPageContextInfo:

- _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl
- _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl